# Compiling Apache httpd into LLVM bytecode using clang

Tags: llvm, clang, apache, llvm-clang

I want to compile **httpd** into LLVM bytecode using **clang**. First I tried compiling it using **gcc**, for which I did the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/varun/apache/httpd/gcc --with-included-apr
make
sudo make install
```

And it successfully installs!

Now, I try compiling it with clang, for which I do the following:

```
CC="clang" CFLAGS="-O4" ./configure --prefix=/home/varun/apache/httpd/clang --with-included-apr
make   # didn't come to this step
sudo make install # didn't come to this step
```

And, the configure itself fails. I chose **-O4** as I read that LLVM outputs bytecode if you use -O4 or -emit-llvm as CFLAGS(neither of them work).

This is the error I get:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/varun/apache/httpd/httpd-2.4.3/srclib/apr':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Is this related to the the linker not being able to link the LLVM bytecode files?

Comment: Thanks @Lei Mou, for editing the question. I should framed the question properly.

Answer (score 3):

[I knew it was something related to the linking step, but was not able to get things working. Finally compilation successful, so I'm writing my own answer]

**Approach 1 (Failed)**

1. Installed clang on my system using the Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Installed binutils-gold, because that is required to give the LLVMgold.so as a plugin to the linker. But for this the clang which was installed, should have the gold plugin.

Trying to configure httpd with this command:

```
CC="clang" CFLAGS="-O4" ./configure --prefix=/home/varun/work/httpd/build --with-included-apr
```

Here, --with-included-apr is required by httpd. -O4 is required so that the compilation happens through bytecode.

This configuration step itself ***fails***, because the clang which is installed doesn't have the proper plugin for enabling the linker to link bytecode object files.

**Approach 2 (Success)**

1. Installed binutils-gold. Also obtained the source of binutils.
2. Compiling LLVM and using the binutils source code to compile, so that LLVM has the gold plugin.

Compile LLVM,

```
../configure --with-binutils-include=/usr/src/binutils/binutils-2.22/include --enable-gold --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

ln -s /usr/local/lib/LLVMgold.so /usr/lib/bdf-plugins/LLVMgold.so
```

Now, compile **httpd**

```
CC="clang" CFLAGS="-O4" ./configure --prefix=/home/varun/work/httpd/build --with-included-apr
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

LLVM bytecode is an intermediate representation used within LLVM. It cannot be executed by any machine. That's why the configure script is complaining that

```
C compiler cannot create executables.
```

Do not output LLVM bytecode. Try to use other optimization level instead. (and don't use `-emit-llvm` in `CFLAGS` as well).

Comment: @varuaa Try this. Specify CC="clang" when executing configure, then type CFLAGS="-O4" make. There might be a linking error during the linking stage, since the GNU linker ld doesn't know anything about LLVM bytecode, then try to specify LD="llvm-ld" when executing the configure script.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question here:

[Generate LLVM IR for httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401450/generate-llvm-ir-for-httpd?rq=1)

It is actually easy to build IR for most well written projects.

Shameless plug for our tool:

https://github.com/SRI-CSL/whole-program-llvm

Good luck.